# Angular: binding to xlink:href does not update SVG in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have an Angular 4 app displaying an SVG. The SVG is dynamic and depends on the model. This is achieved by biding to the `use xlink:href` attribute:

```
<svg class="svg-icon">
  <use [attr.xlink:href]="'./symbol-defs.svg#' + icon" />
</svg>
```

Note that `icon` is a variable and can therefore change. When that happens, the SVG should be updated to reflect this.

Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge, but in IE, the SVG is not updated when the model changes. Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BCRP26wi2VDOPshgyMcI?p=preview) illustrating the problem. It works in all browsers except for IE (11). Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: maybe have multiple use elements (one per icon) then change their display properties so only one is visible?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the svg4everybody module. https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody

Just `npm i --save svg4everybody`

And next for example in AppModule.ts you need add

```
import * as svg4everybody from 'svg4everybody/dist/svg4everybody';
…

ngOnInit() {svg4everybody();}
```